# How to correctly combine javascript with razor syntax

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have the following code in my razor view, I need to set some javascript variables to set the value coming from razor.

However the values of the variables are not being set.

```
var listPuntos =[];
    function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
        @{
            var proveedorID = 0;
            <text>proveedorID = dataItem.ProveedorID</text>
            var list = new UnitOfWork().PuntosVentaProveedorRepository.Get().Where(x => x.ProveedorID == proveedorID);
            proveedorID = 0;
            <text>listPuntos = list; </text>;
            <text>
                var displayText;
                $.each(listPuntos, function (key, value) {
                    if (displayText == undefined)
                        displayText = value.Nombre + ', ';
                    else
                        displayText = displayText + value.Nombre + ', ';
                });
                document.getElementById("puntos").value = displayText.slice(0,-2);
            </text>
        }

    }
```

Comment: Its not clear what your trying to achieve or what results your getting and what your expect. `var list = new UnitOfWork(...` is razor code and is evaluated on the server before its sent to the view (and is the result of `.Where(x => x.ProveedorID == 0)`. Changing the javascript variable - `proveedorID = dataItem.ProveedorID` does not change the result of `var list`.

Comment: If your wanting to filter results on the client you need ajax to call a server method that returns the results that you want, or you need to store everything in the client (assigned to a javascript array) and search that array (but you would only do that if the unfiltered result set is small)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your concrete example, I would start by reducing the number of `<text>` blocks needed by instead just wrapping the *shorter* C# bits with `@{ … }`. This improves readability & lessens confusion. For example:

```
var listPuntos =[];
    function onSelect(e) {
        var dataItem = this.dataSource.view()[e.item.index()];
        @{ var proveedorID = 0; }
        proveedorID = dataItem.ProveedorID;
        @{ var list = new UnitOfWork().PuntosVentaProveedorRepository.Get().Where(x => x.ProveedorID == proveedorID); }
        proveedorID = 0;
        listPuntos = @Json.Encode(list);
        var displayText;
        $.each(listPuntos, function (key, value) {
            if (displayText == undefined)
                displayText = value.Nombre + ', ';
            else
                displayText = displayText + value.Nombre + ', ';
        });
        document.getElementById("puntos").value = displayText.slice(0,-2);
    }
```

Next, to *inject* a C# value into JavaScript code being emitted by the server, you need to encode the value *in JavaScript*. The best way to do this is to convert it into JSON. This is done above using [`Json.Encode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.helpers.json.encode(v=vs.111).aspx). In particular, the line reading:

```
        listPuntos = @Json.Encode(list);
```

I've used `Json.Encode` but of course you are free to use whatever JSON library du jour that fits your project.

Comment: This will only ever return exactly the same results each time it is run because `list` is always the results of `.Where(x => x.ProveedorID == 0)`

Answer (score 1):

you should separate html code and javascript code. 
First at all, don't call any server code from View when View is loading. Push all necessary arrays etc via model property in appropriate format (i.e. in json format) and then fill any client list from value of that property.
Secondly - move code like it :

```
        var displayText;
        $.each(listPuntos, function (key, value) {
            if (displayText == undefined)
                displayText = value.Nombre + ', ';
            else
                displayText = displayText + value.Nombre + ', ';
        });
        document.getElementById("puntos").value = displayText.slice(0,-2);
```

to appropriate section, like it:

```
@section scripts
{
    <script>
.....
    </script>
}
```